# Using webservices with in .Net project from local namespace is valid approach or not?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, web

I am newbie in webservices of .net, i am implementing a project of .net with backend in webservices as i got impressed with the benefits and portability of this architecture.

But the confusion is, i want to know the way i am adopting is right or wrong. I have made services with in my project and calling them from code behind classes, where as my service is implementing the database code. I am attaching the screenshot for further explanation.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not really, when you do this you are calling the classes directly rather than as a service call. This is liable to cause you issues (e.g. if you set up one of your methods to return a certain HTTP response status for example).

If you don't want this to be a service call, then you would be better extracting the logic from the service method into a business layer and have both the service and your page call that code.

---

If you do want a service call, then you need to add a service ref to your project that points to the service and call it through the generated proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach makes no difference of using a C# class vs using a webservice.For this approach You can use a class instead of a webservice.

Use web services instead of C# classes for the following cases.

1. You want to expose some functionality to outside world/consumers/other applications
2. You want to decouple parts of your system so that they can be changed without affecting other parts of application
3. You want to do make your application scaleable, so you create webserices and deploy those on different servers

Comment: I actually want to make a product, which will have different html interfaces with the passage of time, its a property management system which will have different designs later on, but i want to keep the functionality separate, so what you suggest.

Comment: @MuhammadAtifAgha if you are making only one application ,used c# classes but if you are going to make different application with some common functionality make use of Webservice.